# Windows 7 Backup for a system on another drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-8, backup

All this is running on a Windows 8 system, trying to back up a disk containing Windows 7

I've been helping a friend fix her computer, and it seems the hard drive is somewhat broken and close to corruption. I plugged it into my own computer and Windows suggested that I took a backup, which was exactly what I wanted to do. I ended up misconfiguring this, so I had to cancel the backup and try again. After I hit cancel I went into the settings (Windows 7 File Recovery) and now I could only find options to backup my Windows 8 system.

How do I take a backup of the Windows 7 disk now? I can't just simply copy things over. I want the appdata, user directory, user libraries and the OS settings, and Windows 7 backup has always been good like that.

Comment: Where are you trying to save the backup to?  Do you have a secondary drive the same size (or greater)?

Comment: You could try cloning the drive with `dd_rescue`.

Comment: @Kruug Initially, I tried to save the backup to my NAS, but I realized I didn't have enough disk space, so second time I wanted to use my 1 TB internal drive but couldn't set it up. dd_rescue hung during the cloning process.